# Why is F# inferring my function implements IComparable?

Tags: f#, type-inference

I'm a hobbyist programmer (cook by trade) that's currently trying to teach myself F# and functional programming in general.

Anyway, I was fooling around with `DeflateStream` and wrote the following two functions:

```
let Compress compressMe =
    let ds = new DeflateStream(File.Create("compressed.txt"), CompressionMode.Compress)
    File.OpenRead(compressMe).CopyTo(ds)
    ds.Close()

let Decompress =
    let ds = new DeflateStream(File.OpenRead("compressed.txt"), CompressionMode.Decompress)
    ds.CopyTo(File.Create("decompressed.txt"))
    ds.Close()
```

In the body of the main function they are called one right after the other like this:

```
Compress args.[0]
Decompress
```

However, if compressed.txt doesn't exist when the program is run `Decompress` throws a `FileNotFoundException` which is surprising because the only thing that could throw this is the call to `File.OpenRead("compress.txt")`. After about an hour I figured out that `Decompress` was implementing `IComparable` and was being executed before the call to it in the main function. I found that by changing its definition to  `let Decompress () = [...]` it no longer implemented `IComparable` and my code executed as it was intended to. Can anyone tell me why F# was infering `IComparable` and why such and inference would cause the function to execute before the main function marked with `[<EntryPoint>]`? Also, please forgive the imperitive style of my code, I'm incredibly new at this.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: By the way, DeflateStream implements IDisposable, so you should use the "use" keyword rather than "let" to create it. This will ensure the stream is properly Disposed of (and closed) when the stream goes out of scope. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233240(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it seems odd that it inferes IComparable since the type of the expression is unit as far as I can tell (the return type of ds.Close i unit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about the IComparable bit, but the issue you have is that without the parentheses, the compiler is treating `Decompress` as a *value* not a *function*.  This would be similar to if you had written.

```
let compressedName = "compressed.txt"
```

in that case, `compressedName` is now a value.  Adding the parentheses tells the compiler that this is a function whose code must be called each time the function is rather than a value initialized once (before the entry point) by the code you wrote.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was something simple like this.

Answer (score 4):

When you write something like

```
let value = 
    //some long calculation
[<Entrypoint>]
let main args = ...
```

The compiler executes the long calculation before `main`.  This is because you probably use the value later in your code.  To suppress this, as you found, you need to use `let value() = ...`.

I am not sure where `Icomparable` is coming from, but this is the key to what is happening.

Note, if you write

```
let a = ...
let b = ...
```

The compiler will gurantee `a` is calculated before `b` executes.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the absence of parentheses in the declaration is significant.

```
let Decompres = ...
```

declares a variable of type `unit`. This type is used to represent "data" (even if this data doesn't encode much information), and it implements IComparable like any other data-oriented type.

```
let Decompress() = ...
```

declares a function, and functions in F# are not comparable, probably because there is no universally accepted notion of equality on functions.

I can't see that the "IComparable-ness" of `Decompress` had anything to do with the exception you got.